# find for which $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1-\cos(2xy)}{x^2y\sin(\pi y)} & \text{ if } x\neq 0, y\neq 0 \\ 
> c & \text{ if } x= 0 \text{ or } y=0
> \end{cases}$$
> find for which $c \in \mathbb{R}, \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists

I honestly have no idea, looking for a hint on how to even approach this.

Comment: function was written incorrectly, fixed now

Comment: I've found that for points in the form of $(\pi / n, 1/ \pi n)$ the limit seems to be $1/ \pi$. So I assume I should take this as c and try to prove?

Comment: @Joe no, notice the function without c isn't defined on x=0 or y=0 so we have to change it with c so we can even consider the limit.

Comment: The limit is independent of the value ***at*** $(0,0)$, but I missed the ***or***.

Answer (score 1):

According to the identity $\cos(2\alpha) = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(\alpha)$, we can rewrite the given expression as
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-\cos(2xy)}{x^{2}y\sin(\pi y)} = \frac{2\sin^{2}(xy)}{x^{2}y\sin(\pi y)} = \frac{2}{\pi}\times\left(\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\right)^{2}\times\frac{\pi y}{\sin(\pi y)} \xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{2}{\pi}
\end{align*}

where it has been used the well known result that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to 0;z\neq 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z} = 1
\end{align*}